# How to convert PixelAccess object into an image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I cannot find ANY reference to this simply question. There are answers how to save a pixelaccess as a file, which I do not want to do. I only want to convert the pixelaccess object into an image object. I would very much appreciate useful help on that very specific question, character by character and line by line. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. What do you currently have - and please provide code to create something similar. And what do you want as a result?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.